# react-native can't find android sdk

Tags: android, react-native

I have gone through every similar question on here but can't find a solution. I am testing out react-native on my xubuntu 18.04 and I'm stuck on the last step of launching the app on my phone. I have installed android-sdk and it is located in `/usr/lib/android-sdk`,

I also see my device attached when I do `adb devices`

I have added the below inside the .bashrc file and have done `$ source ~/.bashrc` and restarted the terminal and tried running the app again

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/24.0.0:$PATH
```

I keep getting:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and 
have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I also tried the local file approach with local.properties file and adding sdk..what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Please check the version of the sdk installed and the version of the sdk in the gradle

It should be the same.

It worked for me when giving the same versions.